# Components are exposed for all users?

Tags: ms-release-management

I want to create a centralized Release Management server, for our customers but in my tests I'm not able to secure that our components will be safe from change mistakes. For example:

My test was like that:
User 1 - Release Manager (with all permissions)
User 2 - Ordinary user (just permission for approvals)

Logged with my **User 1 - Release Manager (with all permissions)**

First of all I ensured that only Release Managers will have access, and be able to see that release template:
[image: My release template]

I created a new component:
[image: New test component created with the most powerful user]

Then I logged with my **User 2 - Ordinary user (just permission for approvals)**

Firstly I can't see the release template I set permissions above in the release template list. Then I went to the components list and I'm able to see the same component, and even change it. 
[image]

**The main problem** is that after done that, it impacts the releases for all release templates that contains that Component.

I hope to be wrong, and that someone should clarify it to me, that we may secure somehow all components with permission and so on. Any ideas?

Comment: The answer to your question (the title) is Yes, components are exposed to all users. This problem is a little less glaring in the vNext templates where the components do not have a tool associated with them. Security in components is something missing in Release Management agent based Deployment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding security for components is on our backlog. Thanks for the feedback. vNext components do not have tool or execution command stored in them. So, they are a little safer from this issue. Nevertheless, they do have configuration, and you would want to protect that configuration. This feature will be added sometime this year.